# Ошибка «нет доступа к последовательности» при добавлении в базу данных

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
        String login = "postgres";
        String password = "123456";

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,password)) {
            //если убрать с запроса id, выдает ошибку
            String sql = "INSERT INTO all_models (id, name, brand_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 2);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "New model");
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, 1);

            int rows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.printf("%d rows added", rows);

            preparedStatement.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Connection failed...");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Этот код работает, все добавляет, но стоит мне убрать явное указание `id` (он у меня, autoincrement) выдает ошибку:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: нет доступа к последовательности all_models_id_seq
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
at ru.example.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Т.е. система автоматически не может подставлять `id` номер, хотя в Navicate этот запрос работает правильно (`INSERT INTO all_models ("name", "brand_id") VALUES ('New model', '1');`). Как правильно отправлять запрос, что бы `id` автоматически подставлялся БД?

Comment: Права на последовательность [выданы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325017/error-permission-denied-for-sequence-cities-id-seq-using-postgres)? В «navicate» подключаетесь под тем же пользователем?

Comment: Да, конечно. Всё в точности как в Navicate

Comment: Странно. Все-таки, еще раз: если выполнить команду `GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCE all_models_id_seq TO postgres;` и потом перезапустить программу результат не изменится?

Comment: Спасибо большое, установил права пользователя Superuser и выполнил этот команду. Все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно выдать права на последовательность:

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCE all_models_id_seq TO postgres;
```

Или на все последовательности:

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO postgres;
```

Похожий вопрос на английском: [ERROR: permission denied for sequence cities_id_seq using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9325017)